# How to share individual product image in facebook 

Tags: facebook

I'm having product listing page . I would like to show share link for each product and i want to share individual product image . How can i do this ?

I believe meta doesn't help, because i need to share individual product image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your own button for each image, an onclick invoke FB.UI from the JS SDK https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/  passing in the variables you want for the message

So for each image the html could like similar to:

`<img src="path-to-image" title="title" data-uri="path-to-full-product" />`

Then using a library like jquery you could have the following script

```
 $('img').click(function(){
      var $this = $(this);
      var obj = {
      method: 'feed',
      link: $this.data('uri'),
      picture: $this.attr('src'),
      name: $this.attr('title'),
      caption: 'Your caption here',
      description: 'Your description here.'
    };
    function callback(response) {
     alert( "Post ID: " + response['post_id']);
    }

    FB.ui(obj,callback);
 });
```

More info with an example is here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

and you can play around with the JS-SDK here

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/console/

Comment: Can you explain little further.

Comment: I've updated, but I was trying to give you the concepts rather than the code